# Pad numbers with leading zeros in an Access query

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a column of numbers between 0 - 6 digits long.  For those less than 6 I need to pad out with zeros to ensure they are all 6 digits i.e 12563 = 012563 or 23 000023 etc etc.  Can someone recommend a solution?

Answer (score 28):

Probably the easiest way to pad numbers with leading zeros would be to use the `Format()` function, as in

```
Format(fieldName, "000000")
```

Comment: Seems to only work in `Select` queries (as I'm sure it's supposed to). Can't seem to get it to work in an `Update` to format an entire column with leading zeros

Answer (score 3):

If you're searching on this (like for PIN numbers, where '12' would be represented as '000012' here's an example using Gord's correct answer;

```
SELECT CStr(Format(fieldName,"000000")) FROM table WHERE CStr(Format(fieldName,"000000"))="000012";
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I couldn't change the field on the actual file because it was a split database and it had to be changed on the data source (Database_be). I went to the data source and made the change from Number to Short Text to all tables and that was it... Like magic!!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`Update TABLE set DIGITS = string(6- len(DIGITS),"0")`

*DIGITS TABLE* is the table where your numbers are stored.

*DIGITS* is the field that contains your numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The above does NOT work.

Corrected version:

Update TABLE set DIGITS = string(6- len(DIGITS),"0")&DIGITS

The number '6' can be altered for whatever the total length of your field.

Comment: When you say it "does not work" - were you trying it with JET 4.0 under ODBC, OLE-DB, within DAO in VBA, or from within Access' query editor? The difference matters because not all Access SQL features are available in all contexts.